# Dnn Module Packaging Question

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I have folders inside a module which I developed and there are many files inside them.

- How can I package the folders with files?
- Should I archive the folders in a zip file? If so, how can I extract them again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few options.

1. Include a resources.zip file, that will be extracted for you upon installation, just be sure to include the resources.zip in your .dnn file list.
2. If you are using a DNN 5.x manifest, you could keep the folder structure within the module and just use the folder names items in the 5.x manifest.

Comment: I am not using 5.x manifest, I will include zip file with the module, is there a built in method or sth in dnn framework to extraxt the zip file ? Or what is the simplest way to extract zip file in c# ?Thanks.

Comment: The zip file is automatically unzipped by DNN.  DNN modules are deployed as ZIPs.  As the answerer pointed out, you just need to make sure to document all the files in .dnn manifest